# Use ASP.NET to receive JSON data sent from router

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a Billion router periodically send JSON data to cloud server. (There is an API that I can set server name, port, etc where the data should goes.) I want to use an ASP.NET application to retrieve these data then save them to SQL server database.

I did some research, seems that ASP.NET-MVC is a solution?

Right now I have no clue how to do this. I'm a newbie. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: How will you be retrieving the data? Do you have access to some API that the cloud server exposes?

Comment: @Shiva Thank you for your reply! I think I will just parse those JSON data into string and save them to database. I thought the ASP.NET application was the cloud server, so I don't quite understand your second question.

Comment: oh ok. I mis-understood your question. Looks like you are trying to consume an API that returns JSON in an ASP.Net MVC application. I've listed the steps for you in my answer below. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use http://json2csharp.com/ to create strong typed entities from the JSON string. Simply paste the JSON and it will generate the C# entity (class) for you.
2. Use JSON.Net to straight deserialize the JSON strings from Billion Router API into your strong typed entities / classes that you created in step 1. http://james.newtonking.com/json
3. Use Entity Framework or some other ORM to persist the entities you populated in step 2 to the database.

#2 is available as a Nuget Package, so you can simply right click your ASP.Net Project and add it to start using it. http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: Thank you very much! How about listen part? Router broadcast HTTP Post, so how to build a server to get the HTTP Post?

Comment: I forgot to @ you...@Shiva

Comment: @Jun When you say 'Router broadcast HTTP Post' do you mean they are publishing a realtime API feed? If yes, then you'll have to use something like SignalR. If not, and it's a regular HTTP API Server that you make HTTP requests against, then check out the 'World Bank' Sample here => http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/26/asp-net-web-api-and-httpclient-samples.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what realtime API feed is. I built a node.js server like this https://github.com/wzm90/UVGServer/blob/master/server.js and I can receive the data. I just want to do the same thing in C#. Thanks for your help! @Shiva

Comment: It's my bad. The router is not broadcasting, it sent the data to a specific url/ip, and I have a static ip address right now.